# pass javascript array to jqplot chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, jqplot

This is my data..

```
var rname=new Array();
rname.push('India');
rname.push('Pakistan');
rname.push('Australia');
rname.push('America');
rname.push('Sri Lanka');

var rnqi=new Array();
rnqi.push(4);
rnqi.push(6);
rnqi.push(50);
rnqi.push(40);
rnqi.push(5);
```

When I use hardcode like

```
var line1=[['India',4], ['Pakistan',6], ['Australia',50], ['America',40], ['Sri Lanka',5]]
```

Jqchart is working fine, but I want to send the array data(rname and  rqi) ..
Is there any way to send javascript array data to jqplot dynamically??
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var rname = new Array();
    rname.push('India');
    rname.push('Pakistan');
    rname.push('Australia');
    rname.push('America');
    rname.push('Sri Lanka');

    var rnqi = new Array();
    rnqi.push(4);
    rnqi.push(6);
    rnqi.push(50);
    rnqi.push(40);
    rnqi.push(5);

    var result = new Array();
    for (var i = 0, j = 0; i < rname.length, j < rnqi.length; i++, j++) {
        var temp = new Array();
        temp.push(rname[i].toString());
        temp.push(parseInt(rnqi[j]));
        result.push(temp);
    }
    var line1 = [['India', 4], ['Pakistan', 6], ['Australia', 50], ['America', 40], ['Sri Lanka', 5]]
    //now result array is similar to line1
</script>
```

Comment: I have another question..
I want to change the back ground color of that plot..
I am using the jquery.jqplot.css css file.
 `<link type="text/css" href="js/jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" />'
Where I have to change to get the white background for jqplot?

Comment: check this http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html  ------grid option

Comment: marvelous..
Than q,Than q,Than q,Than q,Than q very much.. :-)